# Python automatic build tool

Tags: python, automation, build-automation

at my work i write numerous small python scripts for DB management, most scripts use one or two common libraries which i sometimes update,
before distribution i freeze the scripts with cxfreeze and copy over some resources and upload to a server.

i would like to set up some up some system which would allow me to automatically rebuild/freeze all of the scripts 
, copy over some files, archive and upload to server.

I'm not sure where even to look for such a system, because most of what if found is complicated server based systems like AHP for compiled languages, while i need something small for a single computer

obviously i can write something fast and dirty in python but it seems illogical that there isn't something ready made for these simple requirements.

please forgive my ignorance, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/). From their site:

> Buildout is a Python-based build system for creating, assembling and deploying applications from multiple parts, some of which may be non-Python-based. It lets you create a buildout configuration and reproduce the same software later.

We are using it to do exactly what you describe. It is flexible and easy to extend through recipes.

Comment: tnx, i will, look into it!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)? If you're familiar with it from another language, it might be the easiest. There's also a list on the python wiki [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigurationAndBuildTools).